# Android Build Error when using the barcodescanner and qrscanner at the same time

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

When I use the phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner plugin and the cordova-plugin-qrscanner plugin at the same time in a project, it won't compile for the android plattform. The error it outputs is duplicate permission element in the manifest. Upon checking I saw that this is indeed the case. However manual correction doesn't work as it will be regenerated automatically.

I documented the reproduction scenario further down. It is very simple. Maybe someone has an idea how to solve this issue? Or do you think this is a bug? But where should I open the issue in such a case?

Used version:
Ionic: 3.20.0
cordova: 8.0.0

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start a new project `ionic start permissionissue blank` (when it asks if it should integrate with the iOS and Android platform say yes, when it asks to install the ProSDK say no
2. Change into the project folder: `cd permissionissue`
3. Build it: `ionic cordova build --release android` -> Still everything is fine
4. Install the first plugin: `ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`
5. Build it: `ionic cordova build --release android` -> Still everything is fine
6. Install the second plugin: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-qrscanner`
7. Try to build it: `ionic cordova build --release android` -> Now it breaks

It will show the following error:

```
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
--debug
 option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
23 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 20 up-to-date

(node:12659) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: .../permissionissue/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
.../permissionissue/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-90 Error:
    Element uses-permission#android.permission.CAMERA at AndroidManifest.xml:19:5-90 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-65
.../permissionissue/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-85 Error:
    Element uses-feature#android.hardware.camera at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-85 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-84
.../permissionissue/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    Validation failed, exiting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The generated Manifest looks like this:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

As you can see the CAMERA is once requested by itself and once with required false.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue using cordova-plugin-camera-preview & cordova-plugin-qrscanner

What helped me was:
1. Go to plugins/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/plugin.xml

2. remove entries within

`<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
 ... 
</config-file>`

3. run
   `ionic cordova platform remove android`
4. run
   `ionic cordova platform add android`

This is how my `<platform>` section look like, from `plugin.xml` of `cordova-plugin-qrscanner`

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
      <feature name="QRScanner">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.bitpay.cordova.qrscanner.QRScanner"/>
      </feature>
    </config-file>
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
      <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" /> -->
    </config-file>
    <source-file src="src/android/QRScanner.java" target-dir="src/com/bitpay/cordova/qrscanner"/>
    <framework src="src/android/qrscanner.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference"/>
  </platform>
```

Worked for me, hope it help you as well.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and removed the following lines:
    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
    </config-file>

But now it is unable to compile

Comment: It gives the following (and more) errors:
:app:javaPreCompileRelease
/.../permissionissue/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/com/phonegap/plugins/barcodescanner/BarcodeScanner.java:179: error: cannot find symbol
                        intentScan.putExtra(Intents.Scan.SHOW_FLIP_CAMERA_BUTTON, obj.optBoolean(SHOW_FLIP_CAMERA_BUTTON, false));
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable SHOW_FLIP_CAMERA_BUTTON
  location: class Scan

Comment: If i understand you correctly you removed whole section of `<config-file>`, but I commented out only whats within this tag, like so:    

`<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
      <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
      <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" /> -->
    </config-file>`

Comment: I tried it again and just commented out the one uses-permission and two uses-feature tags. I still get the same error.

Comment: I've added whole `<platform>` section from `cordova-plugin-qrscanner` to the answer. HAve you followed all steps again?